# Conditional Type in Object Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, react-typescript

```
type OperationType = 'Insert' | 'Update' | 'Delete';

export type BaseModel<T extends Document> = {
  operationType:OperationType,
  properties: "Update" extends BaseModel<T>["operationType"]  ? UpdateProperties<T> : Properties<T>,
  model:Model<T>
  validation?:ValidateProp<T>
}
```

I`enter code here` want to switch Property type on behalf of Operation Type but is not working...

Answer (score 0):

In order to observe the specific type of `operationType`, you need to specify its type as a generic like this:

```
export type BaseModel<T extends Document, O extends OperationType> = {
  operationType: O,
  properties: O extends 'Update' ? UpdateProperties<T> : Properties<T>,
  model: Model<T>
  validation?: ValidateProp<T>
}
```

Comment: is still now working What i want Always Apply Properties<T> if I set "Update" in object

Comment: I want Strictly one type apply behalf of Operation Type if Operation  = "Insert" then type apply Properties<T> or Operation  = "Update" then type apply UpdateProperties<T>